# Angular js, pass value to other page

Tags: php, angularjs

I have 2 pages.
Page:1 (index.php)
form data, name, email, phone etc
this data will be pass through angular JS

js page:

```
$scope.insert=function(){ $http.post("insert.php",{
       'name':$scope.name,
       'email':$scope.email}) 
    .success(function(datasuccess){
       $scope.name=datasuccess.name;
    $scope.email=datasuccess.email; 
    $scope.phone=datasuccess.phone; 
    $scope.cardDisplay();
    });
    };
```

page :1 (insert.php)

```
$datasuccess[]="Person Name";
    $datasuccess[]="Person email";
    $datasuccess[]="phone";
    print json_encode($datasuccess);
```

After success insert.php page jason data need to show to my index.php page

```
{{datasuccess.email}}
{{datasuccess.name}}
```

Ok in my index.php page have a form, after submit the data it will goes through angularJS in insert.php, after insert some data in insert.php page then from that page (insert.php) will return some data to index.php My angular code:

```
$scope.insert=function(){ $http.post("insert.php",{
   'name':$scope.name,
   'email':$scope.email}) 
.success(function(datasuccess){
   $scope.name=datasuccess.name;
$scope.email=datasuccess.email; 
$scope.phone=datasuccess.phone; 
$scope.cardDisplay();
});
};
```

Comment: Use $location.search() to extract the query string parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Create an associated array

```
$datasuccess = array(
    "name" => "Person Name",
    "email" => "Person email",
    "phone" => "phone"
);
echo json_encode($datasuccess);
```

And on the client side (JS) you'll get it as a JSON, with properties as reference from the server:

```
$scope.name = datasuccess.name;
```

Then you will be able to bind the information to the view simple by doing:

```
{{ name }}
```

Or:

```
<span ng-bind="name"></span>
```

Comment: somehow i need to use following function to get data like 
`.success(function(datasuccess){
                    $scope.name = datasuccess.name;
$scope.email = datasuccess.email;
                    $scope.pDisplay();
                })`
how can i do something like this?

Comment: OK, so if you return the array as described in the question, then you should be able to use it like that

Comment: I am new in Angular Js, can you give me the angular js and page3.php page code for that?

Comment: @ShimulChowdhury I have added details how to show it in the view, but you need to show more code in order for me to understand what you're trying to do

Comment: Ok in my index.php page have a form, after submit the data it will goes through angularJS in insert.php, after insert some data in insert.php page then from that page (insert.php) will return some data to index.php 
My angular code:
`$scope.insert=function(){
        $http.post("insert.php",{'name':$scope.name,
            'email':$scope.email})
                .success(function(datasuccess){
                    $scope.name=datasuccess.name;
$scope.email=datasuccess.email;
$scope.phone=datasuccess.phone;
                    $scope.cardDisplay();
                });
        };`

Comment: @ShimulChowdhury Please include this in the question body, it will make the code readable and allow others to help you as well (Click on the `edit` link under the tags of the question

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not thinking in angular way, but one solution is to use `$rootScope`, simply inject this in your controller and share variables across your views, you can also create a `service` and assign those values to your service and use that service in your controllers.

```
controller('MainController', function($rootScope) {
      $rootScope.name = datasuccess.name;
});
```

and in your view you can simply access `$rootScope` as `$root`:

page index.html

```
<div>
    {{$root.name}}
</div>
```

page2.html

```
<div>
    {{$root.name}}
</div>
```